# How do you get when you click each word/name, certain div show?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm doing a site where, when I click on the Alagoas word "div_alagoas" appears. When I click on the BAHIA word, "div_alagoas and hide" "div_bahia" show.

In this example, I tested with input Radio and it worked. But I do not know how to work with the tags `<li> <a>`.

How can I do that?

HTML:

```
 <form>
      <li><a name="alagoas" id="ala">ALAGOAS </a></li>
          <br>
      <li><a name="alagoas" id="ba">BAHIA </a></li>
</form>


 <div id="div_alagoas" value="alagoas" style="border:1px solid black">

    content

 </div>
 <div id="div_bahia" value="bahia" style="border:1px solid black">

    content

 </div>
```

JQUERY:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('  ???  [name=alagoas]').change(function(){
        if(this.id == 'ala'){
                $('#div_alagoas').show();
                $('#div_bahia').hide();
        }
        else if (this.id == 'ba'){
                $('#div_bahia').show();
                $('#div_alagoas').hide();


        }
    });
});
```

Comment: just remove the ??? and switch from change to click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, if you want a click listener:

```
$('[name=alagoas]').click(function(event){
    if($(event.target).attr('id') === 'ala'){
            $('#div_alagoas').show();
            $('#div_bahia').hide();
    }
    else if ($(event.target).attr('id') === 'ba'){
            $('#div_bahia').show();
            $('#div_alagoas').hide();
    }
});
```

Another note, your HTML should be better formatted, like putting `li` tags inside a `ul` or `ol`

```
<ul>
    <li><a name="alagoas" id="ala">ALAGOAS </a></li>
    <li><a name="alagoas" id="ba">BAHIA </a></li>
</ul>
```

Another way to do this is splitting into different listeners:

```
$('#ala').click(function(){ 
    $('#div_alagoas').show();
    $('#div_bahia').hide();
});

$('#ba').click(function(){ 
    $('#div_alagoas').hide();
    $('#div_bahia').show();
});
```

Comment: That was exactly what I needed, it's worked, thanks!